# Plot implicit surface from arrays in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Suppose I have four one-dimensional numpy arrays, `x`, `y`, `z`, and `value`. The point `(x[i],y[i],z[i])` is part of the surface if and only if `value[i]=0`. Is there a way to plot this surface in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply boolean indexing on numpy arrays x,y,z like shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
z = np.random.random(10)
value = np.random.randint(2,size=10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x[value==0], y[value==0], z[value==0])
plt.show()
```

In this example, scatter plot is shown but you can do the same thing for surface plot.